# Using Partial Derivatives to find the equation of a tangent plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$z = 4(x-1)^2 + 5(y+3)^2 +1$ at the point $(2,-2,10)$

I'm not sure how exactly how to proceed through the problem. I know to find the derivative with respect to $x$ , $y$, and $z$, which I did. For $x$, I got $8(x-1)$ and for $y$, I got $10(y+3)$. When I found $z$, I got was pretty much the sum of the derivatives of $x$ and $y$ . I know I'm supposed to plug in the point $(2,-2,10)$ somewhere, but I'm not sure if it is the original question or the derived formulas.

Comment: The equation of the tangent plane of a function $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ at a point $(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))$ is given by $$z=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0).$$ Apply it to your problem with $f(x,y)=4(x-1)^2+5(y+3)^2+1$ (for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$) and $(x_0,y_0)=(2,-2)$. You should start by confirming that $f(2,-2)=10$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the gradient is normal to the level surface.  Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\vec N&=\nabla f(\vec r)\\\\
&=\hat x\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+\hat y\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\\\\
&=\hat x(8(x-1))+\hat y(10(y+3))
\end{align}$$

At the point $(2,-2,10)$, the normal is

$N=\hat x8+\hat y10$.  The equation of the tangent plane is then

$$\vec N\cdot (\vec r-\vec r_0)\implies 4x+5y=-2$$